# How to add some text to start and end of each element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array. I want to add some characters (`:,\n`) to each element in that array to be shown in a text box.

Currently this is what I'm doing

```
$scope.source.arr = .... //This is an array
var actualText = "";

function func() {
    $scope.source.arr.forEach(function(ele){
        actualText += "***" + ele + " - \n"; //Adding necessary characters
    })
}

var showText = function() {
    func(); //Calling the function that populates the text as needed
    var textBox = {
          text : actualText; 
          ...
     }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new Array object with the changed strings, like this

```
var textBox = {
      text: $scope.source.arr.map(function(ele) {
          return "***" + ele + " -  ";
      }).join("\n"),
      ...
 };
```

For each element in the `arr`, we are creating a new string corresponding to it and creating an array of strings. Finally we join all the strings in the array with `\n`.

Comment: So if my understanding if correct the function won't return string for each element but returns array of string (string representation) for the entire array. Am I right?

Comment: @user7 The function passed to `map` will be called for all the items in the array and all the returned values from the function calls will be collected and returned as an array. That array will be joined with the `join` function to get a single string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.prototype.map, Array.prototype.reduce to make it better.

Check reduce function here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```
var prefix = "***";
var postfix = "$$$";

var targetStrArr = ["apple", "banana"]

var resultStr = targetStrArr.map(function(ele){
    return prefix + ele + postfix; //Adding necessary characters
}).reduce(function(prevVal, curVal) {
    return prevVal + curVal;
});

console.log(resultStr); // ***apple$$$***banana$$$
```